# Visual Studio 2010 Debugger - Structures debug info still holding old member names and types, not updating

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

In visual studio 2010, the debugger is still displaying structure information of older structures, even though there are new types and names, or if all members were replaced, name of structure changed, etc... I've tried deleting the project pdb, but it regenerates itself after rebuilding and the old structure information is still there at runtime. It's making it impossible to debug linked list trees.

Is there any way to completely reset the internal debugger information and force it to recognize the new structure layout?

Comment: Did you check the "modules" list to verify that (a) you are picking up your new PDBs and (b) actually running your newly built program instead of some old one?

Comment: Even when I start a new project, somehow it is associating old structure names with the new projects in the debugger. It's seriously jacked. I can't figure out where the debugger's getting its info from to begin with so I can delete it.

Comment: I should also note that the debugger realizes that the structure data it has is incoherent, because it is all represented as invalid data. The program itself works correctly, values are being calculated and stored correctly, but the debugger has no idea what the layout of the structures is. I had to resort to printing a log file to verify the process without the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Debug->Windows->Modules

Spot your module and check the location it is being picked from

Check where the pdb for this module is being loaded from

Delete these pdbs and dlls

Clear Symbol Cache from Debug->Options->Debugging->Symbols

Now recompile and retry

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution: deleting the .pdb for the projects and all sub-projects fixed the problem for me